# PHP get number of words from a string not characters

Tags: php

I have long string where I want to get only few **words** not characters.

Currently, this code is cut 100 characters from the variable but I want to cut **150 words**:

```
$content = substr( $content, 0, 100 );
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you define "words" as characters delimited by spaces?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Comment: @showdev I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your words are separated by white-space, you can simply `explode` the string to an array with a maximum of 151 elements, throw away the last one and then `implode` the array to re-form the string e.g.

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $content, 151);
array_pop($words);
echo implode(' ', $words);
```

Note I've used `preg_split` rather than `explode` to ensure words separated by a newline are split properly.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5e985)

Comment: The correct way to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

A work around it but not ideal. There is possibly a cleaner way to do this.

```
$array = explode(' ', $content);
$newString = '';
for($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++){
    if(isset($array[$i])){
        if($i != 0){
            $newString .= ' ';
        }
        $newString .= $array[$i];
    }
}
echo $newString;
```

You can then modify the '$i < 150' to get the word places that you need.